# Encryption using AWS KMS Asymmetric key

Tags: reactjs, amazon-kms

I am trying to apply client side encryption, for this using AWS KMS I created Asymmetric key. I downloaded the public key and then from the frontend (I am using react). I am using the following function to encrypt the data

```
function encryptMessage(message, publicKey) {
  const jsEncrypt = new JSEncrypt();
  jsEncrypt.setPublicKey(publicKey);
 
  return jsEncrypt.encrypt(message);
}
```

I later encode this in base64 before sending it,

The key spec is RSA_2048

And I want to use RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256 as my encryption algorithm.

Following is the backend, written in python to decrypt the message:

```
client = boto3.client('kms')
res = base64.b64decode(blob)
print(res)
response = client.decrypt(
    CiphertextBlob=res,
    KeyId='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    EncryptionAlgorithm='RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256'
)
print(response)
```

I am unable to send a proper encrypted message so that it can be decrypted from backend.
How do I set EncryptionAlgorithm on react?

Comment: As far as I know, JSEncrypt supports only PKCS#1 v1.5 but no OAEP as padding, s. [here](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/issues/84). I am not familiar with boto3, but according to the documentation it seems to support only OAEP for RSA. Also, it appears that the ciphertext is expected in a special format (including some metadata), s. [`client#encrypt`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kms.html#KMS.Client.encrypt) and [`client#decrypt`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kms.html#KMS.Client.decrypt).

Comment: Okay thanks, and is there any way we can use this to decrypt data on react client side?

Comment: Do you mean decryption or encryption? For encryption you have to use a library on the client side that applies OAEP like the server side, that means not JSEncrypt. For decryption the private key is needed. Although the decryption on the client side makes no sense to me for the above scenario (maybe I misunderstood something).

Comment: Okay, I was thinking if it is wise to encrypt data from server to client as well

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?